# check for event midway through running while loop?

Tags: python, pygame

So with pygame you have a while loop that loops continuously, then your event handlers in a for loop, then the code you want to execute continuously.

I need to handle an event after i execute a line of code inside the while loop though beacuse they impact each other, but I also need to handle a different event before the line.

How, inside my main while loop, handle a set of events, execute some code, and then handle another set of events?

Comment: I have a quit event, a user event, 4 keydown events, and 2 keyup events. I also have a line of code that blits a background and a function that blits an image (supposed to blit it on top of the background, but it doesn't because of the order). I call the function with my user event handler. I tried the following order: while loop, for loop (quit event, 4 keydown events, 2 keyup events), blit, for loop(user event). I'll edit the post and show you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I set a variable equal to 1 in the user event handler, and then down where i needed to execute the code, i check if the variable was equal to 1, and if it was, i executed my code and set the variable back to 0.

Good stuff.

Here is my code if anyone wants to help me find a better solution ;) (kinda long):

```
uif = "images/userGray.png"
bif = "images/bg.jpg"
cif = "images/chair3.png"
i = 0
playerX = 1
playerY = 1
pX = 1
pY = 1
bX = 0
bY = 0
moveX = 0
moveY = 0
windowX = 640
windowY = 480
lowerY = 1024
lowerX = 1024
bullets = []
x = 0
y = 0
rotate = False

objects = []

objects.append([256,260,410,511])

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
user = pygame.image.load(uif).convert_alpha()
chair = pygame.image.load(cif).convert_alpha()
chair1 = pygame.image.load(cif).convert_alpha()

pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 100)

def shoot(inLoc, clLoc, weapon):
    bulletId = len(bullets)
    bullets[bulletId] = [inLoc, clLoc, 200, 3]

moveSpeed = .1

while True:



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == USEREVENT + 1:
            rotate = True;
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveX = -1*moveSpeed
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveX = moveSpeed
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveY = moveSpeed
            elif event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveY = -1*moveSpeed
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a or event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveX = 0
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s or event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveY = 0

    dontMoveX = 0
    dontMoveY = 0

    for obj in objects:

        if playerX + moveX > obj[0]-user.get_width() and playerX + moveX < obj[1] and playerY + moveY > obj[2]-user.get_height() and playerY + moveY < obj[3]:
            if playerY + moveY == obj[2]-user.get_height()-1 or playerY + moveY == obj[3]+1:
                dontMoveX = 0
            else:
                dontMoveX = 1

        if playerX + moveX > obj[0]-user.get_width() and playerX + moveX < obj[1] and playerY + moveY > obj[2]-user.get_height() and playerY + moveY < obj[3]:
            if playerX + moveX == obj[0]-user.get_width()-1 or playerX + moveX == obj[1]+1:
                dontMoveY = 0
            else:
                dontMoveY = 1

    if dontMoveX == 0:
        playerX += moveX

        if (playerX >= 0 and playerX <= windowX/2) or (playerX >= lowerX-(windowX/2) and playerX <= lowerX-user.get_width()):
            pX+=moveX
        if playerX > windowX/2 and playerX < lowerX-(windowX/2):
            bX+=-1*moveX

    if dontMoveY == 0:
        playerY += moveY

        if (playerY >= 0 and playerY <= windowY/2) or (playerY >= lowerY-(windowY/2) and playerY <= lowerY-user.get_width()):
            pY+=moveY
        if playerY > windowY/2 and playerY < lowerY-(windowY/2):
            bY+=-1*moveY

    screen.blit(background,(bX,bY))



    screen.blit(user,(pX,pY))


    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False);

    if rotate == True:    

        if i < 360:
            i = i + 18
        else:
            i = 0

        orig_chair_rect = chair.get_rect()
        chair1 = pygame.transform.rotate(chair, i);
        rot_chair_rect = orig_chair_rect.copy()
        rot_chair_rect.center = chair1.get_rect().center
        chair1 = chair1.subsurface(rot_chair_rect).copy()

        rotate = False

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= chair.get_width()/2
    y -= chair.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(chair1,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: That sounds kind of roundabout. Why don't you post what you have done and see if someone can point out a better solution?

Comment: edited with complete code. i'm new, so i probably have a bunch of other problems too.